# sed to php preg_match regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this string:

```
$str = "Samples read:           2748264
        Length (seconds):     31.159456
        Scaled by:         2147483647.0";
```

And on the command line, if I want to extract the value after Length (seconds): I can use sed like so:

```
sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'
```

How might I reformat this into php's regex matching format? I only need the number directly after Length (seconds):, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    preg_match('/Length \(seconds\):\s+(.*?)Scale/is', $str,$m);
    echo $m[1];
```

Comment: Instead of going until Scale, you can go to the end of the line with `$`.

Comment: You're right.  I just dumped it into a sandbox and it does.  I edited my comment.  Didn't work on liveregex for some reason, I must have copied the regex wrong.

Comment: strange, but I copied you code to a sandbox script as: preg_match('/Length \(seconds\):\s*([0-9.]*)$/', $str,$m); and got empty result

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that too, but it works fine on live regex. I'm checking it out

Answer (score 0):

`sed` uses some strange (old?) variant of `regex` and it requires to escape the parenthesis in order to create a group and leave them unescaped to interpret them literally.

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) uses [`Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

What you need to change:

- invert the escaping of parenthesis;
- quote the dot (`.`) in the group you want to match (otherwise it will match any character); I think it should be quoted for `sed` too;
- either change the `^` and `$` anchors to match the input text (it has space characters at the begining of the lines) or make sure the string you want to match (`Length`) always appears a the start of the line in the input text (no padding); I added a non-capturing group (`(?:\s*)`) to match zero or more whitespace characters at the beginning of the line;
- add the `m` modifier (`multi-line`) to allow `^` and `$` match at beginning and end of line; without it they match only the start and the end of the input string.

The code:

```
$str = "Samples read:           2748264
        Length (seconds):     31.159456
        Scaled by:         2147483647.0";

$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('#^(?:\s*)Length \(seconds\):[^0-9]*([0-9\.]*)$#m', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 31.159456
)
```

If you know the string you want to match appears only once in the input string (or if you want to match only its first appearance) then you can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead of [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and it will store a string in `$matches[1]` (if a match was found).